# Android: what does this Paint flag do: DEV_KERN_TEXT_FLAG?

Tags: android, paint

I cannot find anything informative about the purpose of this flag.  Does anyone know?

Thank you

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Kerning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerning) is a typographical technique.

[image: Kerning]

Comment: Kerning I've heard of. But what is "DEVICE" kerning? If it means "turn on kerning on this device," well that makes no sense, because why is the anti-aliasing flag called just "ANTI_ALIAS" instead of "DEV_ANTI_ALIAS"? The Paint documentation for Android seems pretty poor in general. E.g., anti aliasing doesn't say *what* gets antialiased, so I had to experiment to discover that paths and text are anti-aliased, while clip regions are not. Etc.

Comment: After experimenting with DEV_KERN_TEXT_FLAG a little, it seems to have no effect on my TextView

Comment: Yeah but does it actually introduce font kerning?  I don't think it does despite being the default flag that all Paint instances are constructed with.  Plus why is DEV prepended to the constant?

Comment: Disabling this flag just causes wrong measurements returned in Paint.getTextWidths() in Android 4.1 and Android 4.2. In Android 4.3 it has no effect. In any case the kerning of the text painted is not affected.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html):

An integer bit mask for the flag enabling device kerning for text.

(or does that not count as something informative?)

Comment: does not count to me as well.